# NS_ERROR_FAILURE Virtual Machine Doesn't Run

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, virtualization

When I try to start my virtual machine(Fully set up) It doesn't startup. Here's the error :

```
Waiting for VM "vm-server" to power on...
VBoxManage: error: Nonexistent host networking interface, name 'vmnet1' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

This is the command I used to start it up :

```
VBoxManage startvm vm-server --type headless
```

The vm's os is Ubuntu 20.04, as is the computer. I will also point out that the computer is accessed by ssh if that is required information. I do not have any Windows installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a recent change in VirtualBox behavior, look for updates/upgrades.  Frequently, when Ubuntu or other distributions update it will cause VB to fail with that message.

Solution for me has always been to remove VB and install the latest version together with the VB Extension Pack which, (on Sept. 17, 2020) is version 6.1.14 for both.

Make sure you install both! I download mine directly from the Oracle Virtualbox website.